# Output of Assembly code - Confusion with add?

Tags: c++, assembly, mips, addition

I just started learning Assembly and in one exercise I have to find the output of the following code, but since I'm very new, I'm not sure what it is and that's mainly because of **`add`**.

**Assembly Code:**

```
addi $8, $0, 0     # $8 = $0 + 0 = 0 + 0 = 0
addi $9, $0, 8     # $9 = $0 + 8 = 0 + 8 = 8
L1:
    add $4, $0, $8      # $4 = $0 + $8 = $8
    addi $2, $0, 1     # $2 = $0 + 1 = 0 + 1 = 1
    addi $8, $8, 1     # $8 = $8 + 1
    syscall     # show the number in $4 
bne $8, $9, L1     # if $8 ≠ $9 go to L1 (line 3)
```

The way I look at it, the above code should output the numbers **`0-7`**, but since I'm new to Assembly, I thought of translating the code to C++ to figure it out, but in C++ I got **`1-8`**, because I was inclined to translate **`add $4, $0, $8`** as **`$4 = &$8`**.

**C++ Code:**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  int $0 = 0, $2, $8, $9, *$4;

  $8 = $0 + 0;      // $8 = 0
  $9 = $0 + 8;      // $9 = 8

  do {
    $4 = &$8;
    $2 = $0 + 1;
    $8 = $8 + 1;
    cout << *$4 << endl;
  }
  while ($8 != $9);
  return 0;
}
```

**Question:** Is Assembly's **`add $4, $0, $8`** to be thought of as **`$4`** being a pointer to **`$8`** or simply equal to what **`$8`** is at the time. *(The confusion has been created by the comment next to **`add`**)*.

Comment: While the C++ is _valid_ as pseudo code for prototyping the mips asm, consider changing (e.g.) `$0` into `r0` [likewise for others], if for no other reason to make it compile more cleanly and quiet LLs. However, IIRC, there may be a compile option to allow `$` in symbols anyway

Comment: Thanks for the tip @CraigEstey :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting the value of $4 to the value of $8, whatever it is when that instruction is executed. Your code is saying that since you are adding the value of $8 to $0, it is the same as just loading the value of $8 into $4.

Note, you can accomplish the same thing by using `move $4 $8`.

Comment: So it outputs **`0-7`**?

Comment: To set $4 to the address of $8, you would have to use `la $4 $8`.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by Zach your C++ code is setting $4 to the value of the address of $8 but the assembly is setting the value of $4 to $8.  Thus the correct C++ code is below.  What it prints out is left as an exercise!

Additionally $2 is just set for the syscall, so we don't need it in our C++ code: I've removed it to get rid of the "unused variable" warning.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  int $0 = 0, $8, $9, $4;

  $8 = $0 + 0;      // $8 = 0
  $9 = $0 + 8;      // $9 = 8

  do {
    $4 = $8;
    $8 = $8 + 1;
    cout << $4 << endl;
  }
  while ($8 != $9);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @dave. What do you mean ***$2 is just set for the syscall***? I was wondering why it even exists in the Assembly code since it's not used.

Comment: @AngelPolitis: You have to tell the operating system _which_ system call you want to execute.  I'm assuming from the code that the syscall number is passed in $2, but you'd have to check your documentation for that.

Comment: You are right. The exercise says *''to output an integer, we must set $2 to 1 and put the value we want to print to $4''*. It's not clear to me why **`$2`** and why **`$4`**, but I guess I'll figure it out as I learn. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @AngelPolitis: It is called the syscall ABI (application binary interface as opposed to application programming interface).  That will make it easier to search and ask questions about it if you have those!